# How to unlock admin console account in wso2 5.10 version Identity Service

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 IS 5.10 version. Our admin account got locked might be 3 wrong password attempt. If auto account lock time set to 0 then how can we unlock the admin account. Since account is locked so it is not allowing to call any SCIM API with admin authorization. We tried to restart kubernetes pod but it is not allowing to restart stating admin account is locked.
Can any one help to get admin account unlocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few ways you can try to unlock the admin account. You can try the below options.

***Option 01***
Wait till it gets recovered automatically.
In the following configuration parameter, you set up the Lock. Time for each account upon the consecutive login account failure attempts. Please note this value takes Minutes, NOT seconds.
In this scenario, the accounts will be locked for 5 minutes.[image]

***Option 02***
Restart the server using the `-DunlockAdmin` system property. There were some cases this property didn't work as expected.

***Option 03***
As a last resort, you can change the configurations from the database level and unlock the relevant Admin account.
The table you are looking for is in the Access Management database or `WSO2IDENTITY_DB` database, and the table name `IDN_IDENTITY_USER_DATA`. To enable the H2 Console, you can add the below configuration in **deployment.toml** file in **<IS_HOME>/repository/conf**

```
[database_configuration]
enable_h2_console = "true"
```

Then you can go to `localhost:8082` and can log in to H2-console.
[image]
For the 'admin' username (or any other username) there will be some DATA_KEY available in the table, we don't need all of them, what we need;

```
http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountLocked
http://wso2.org/claims/identity/unlockTime
```

[image]
in normal behaviour, correspondent account locked `DATA_VALUE` must be `false` and `unlockTime` should be `0`.

```
    UPDATE IDN_IDENTITY_USER_DATA SET DATA_VALUE='false'  WHERE DATA_KEY='http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountLocked' AND USER_NAME='admin'

    UPDATE IDN_IDENTITY_USER_DATA SET DATA_VALUE='0' WHERE DATA_KEY='http://wso2.org/claims/identity/unlockTime' AND USER_NAME='admin';
```

[image]
After you have done updating the values, you need to restart the IS server. Because in the configurations we have set up originally, have stated after how long we need to unlock the account.

Comment: Thanks @Maneesha Indrachapa for detailed response. I knew about first option but unfortunately for testing purpose I kept 0 min as Account unlock time. So it was not allowing to restart server even. Later I did update the unlock flag as true then it worked.  Option 2 I was not aware and did not try. Thanks any way..

Comment: @Rajeev.Ranjan happy to help :)